# captcha that works with very high traffic

Tags: php, captcha

My website is on php and I want to integrate a good captcha in my website.

The traffic of the website is very high so most of the free available captcha either have issues on my server or they just fail and annoy my users.

Please let me know a good captcha software written in php which can handle very huge amount of traffic.

Comment: What issues do the captchas have on your server? How do they fail? Do you know for sure they fail because of high traffic?

Comment: If you need astonishing performance, then search for some C utility to generate the captcha images (instead of php/gd script), or use a math/text riddle instead. Or another thought: consider an external service like reCaptcha.

Comment: @Pekka I am not sure why it fails, but users enter the correct code but it shows errors (secure image failed very badly)

Comment: If your captcha should be able to handle high amounts of traffic, could you then indicate what you consider "high"? Also a captcha will probably always annoy users, even though it gets more and more accepted it still means they have to fill out more fields (and try to decypher an image).

Comment: @Arjan if there was a solution, popular websites like facebook and yahoo should have adopted them first so its like a necessity

Comment: @Dee Jay: Facebook required you to register before you can leave comments, so they don't have to use captchas.

Comment: @Arjan lol ... post one link 10 and see the majic of captcha after registration for the 11th

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). It's a very widely used external 
captcha service.

> - Free
> - Strong security
> - Accessible to blind users
> - 30+ million served daily
> - Hosted by Google (you don't host the images nor script that generates them)
> - Helps digitization of text

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid image-based CAPTCHA systems, you can always use math questions:

- What is the sum of three and five?
- Two multiplied by six is what?
- etc etc.

Keep a table of questions/responses and validate their response with the correct one. Works well, and fast.

Comment: I do not want to waste another day writing something that a million people have already developed (no offense seriously) ... Please let me know if you know an already written script like this. Thank you!

Comment: I do not off the top of my head, but [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=text+captcha) sure does.

Comment: Pfft those questions are easy :)  I always liked the captcha at http://random.irb.hr/signup.php

Comment: @James Easy is preferred for your users' sake. You're trying to prevent robots from accessing the site, not people who don't understand algebra. Simple word problems are (so far) rather effective at this.